# Using Greensock (gsap) with Gatsby react static site error animation.gsap

Tags: animation, gsap, gatsby

When attempting to create an animation in a Gatsby site, I get the following error:

```
12:57:12:665 (ScrollMagic.Scene) -> ERROR calling setTween() due to missing Plugin 'animation.gsap'. Please make sure to include plugins/animation.gsap.js
```

I have found resources referencing adding the plugin into the gatsby-config.js, also the gatsby-browser.js but not exactly how to code that plugin add.

Current gatsby.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
   siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Gatsby Default Starter',
  },
  plugins: ['gatsby-plugin-react-helmet', 'gatsby-plugin-emotion'],
}
```

Current gatsby-browser.js:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import 'babel-polyfill'
import React, { createElement } from 'react'

exports.onClientEntry = () => {
  require('gsap')
  require('scrollmagic')
  require('gsap/src/uncompressed/plugins/ScrollToPlugin')
  require('jquery')
}
```

How do I bring in animation.gsap plugin?

My animation component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import styled from 'react-emotion'
import { TweenLite as Tween, TimelineMax as Timeline, TweenMax } from 'gsap'
import { Images } from '../../assets'
import '../../styles/main.css'
import $ from 'jquery'
import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic'

const Container = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 999;
`

export default class Animation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const flightpath = {
      entry: {
        curviness: 1.25,
        autoRotate: true,
        values: [{ x: 100, y: -20 }, { x: 300, y: 10 }, {}],
      },
      looping: {
        curviness: 1.25,
        autoRotate: true,
        values: [
          { x: 510, y: 60 },
          { x: 620, y: -60 },
          { x: 500, y: -100 },
          { x: 380, y: 20 },
          { x: 500, y: 60 },
          { x: 580, y: 20 },
          { x: 620, y: 15 },
        ],
      },
      leave: {
        curviness: 1.25,
        autoRotate: true,
        values: [
          { x: 660, y: 20 },
          { x: 800, y: 130 },
          { x: $(window).width() + 300, y: -100 },
        ],
      },
    }

    //init controller
    const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller()

    //create tween
    const tween = new Timeline()
      .add(
        TweenMax.to($('#plane'), 1.2, {
          css: { bezier: flightpath.entry },
          ease: Power1.easeInOut,
        })
      )
      .add(
        TweenMax.to($('#plane'), 2, {
          css: { bezier: flightpath.looping },
          ease: Power1.easeInOut,
        })
      )
      .add(
        TweenMax.to($('#plane'), 1, {
          css: { bezier: flightpath.leave },
          ease: Power1.easeInOut,
        })
      )

    // build scene
    const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#trigger',
      duration: 500,
      offset: 100,
    })
      .setPin('#target')
      .setTween(tween)
      .addTo(controller)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <div className="spacer s2" />
        <div className="spacer s0" id="trigger" />
        <div id="target">
          <img id="plane" src={Images.pou} />
        </div>
        <div className="spacer s2" />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully added gsap (greensock) into my react component in gatsby the following way.

```
npm install gsap --save
```

and then inside the react component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TweenMax} from 'gsap';

export default class MyAnimation extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    TweenMax.set(this.myObject, { transformOrigin: '50% 50%' });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="myObject"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that animation.gsap has no ES6 export.

I ended up copying all the code and wrapped it in an export.
The same goes for debug.addIndicators.js.

You can see it here:

https://github.com/bitworking/react-scrollmagic/blob/master/src/animation.gsap.js

https://github.com/bitworking/react-scrollmagic/blob/master/src/debug.addIndicators.js

Then import it and run it:

```
import { default as ScrollMagic } from 'scrollmagic';
import { TimelineMax as Timeline, TweenMax as Tween } from 'gsap/TweenMax';

import animationGsap from './animation.gsap.js';
import debugAddIndicators from './debug.addIndicators.js';

animationGsap(ScrollMagic, Timeline, Tween);
debugAddIndicators(ScrollMagic);
```

Or you can use the following packages for React:

ScrollMagic + GSAP
https://github.com/bitworking/react-scrollmagic

Only GSAP:
https://github.com/bitworking/react-gsap

Answer (score 1):

For me work this:
use command in root folder `cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js`
and next in src/html.js add your links and code before end of body tags:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TimelineLite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>


    <script
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {
      {
        __html: `
        window.onscroll = function () {
          var logo = document.querySelectorAll(".logo");
            TweenLite.from(logo, 2, {
              opacity: 1,
              left: "300px",
              color: "#fff"
            });
        }
    `,
      }
    }
    />
```

[Docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is a bit obsolete, but anyway I can leave my current solution just for reference.
Checkout this plugin scrollmagic-plugin-gsap. As it is mentioned in the documentation, animation.gsap.js is not compatible with ES6 modules.

```
import ScrollMagic from "scrollmagic";
import gsap from "gsap";
import { ScrollMagicPluginGsap } from "scrollmagic-plugin-gsap";

ScrollMagicPluginGsap(ScrollMagic, gsap);

const MyComponent = () => {
  //...
}
```